# Should I change the 'preconnect' URLs from href="//" to href="https://"?

Tags: html, performance, page-speed, cross-origin

In order to speed up the load of my webpages, that use ads from Google Adsense, I'm considering to modify the following 'preconnect' directives:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//adservice.google.com/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//www.googletagservices.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//tpc.googlesyndication.com">
```

with these other ones:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://adservice.google.com/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.googletagservices.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com">
```

Is it a good idea? Would it actually speed up the load of my webpages?

Comment: Is your page available over `http://` or is always only secure over `https://`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you end up loading those resources over HTTPS later in your document? If so, I believe the protocol-relative URL might actually be an antipattern here. If your page ever gets loaded over HTTP, then the preconnected HTTP connections will need to be scrapped later on in the page life cycle so that the browser can establish HTTPS connections, meaning that the preconnects actually had a small net negative performance impact. I am not sure how preconnects behave for domains like Google's that likely have an immediate redirect to HTTPS (whether HTTP-level or internal HSTS), but I believe it's best to [avoid protocol-agnostic URLs entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454204/2234742) because then you don't have to think about it.

The no-brainer solution is to change your preconnects to use HTTPS and make sure those resources are all requested over HTTPS when they are actually needed. Using protocol-agnostic URLs may not be an issue in this case for many reasons, but there is no reason to use them, and using all-HTTPS links is guaranteed to not cause issues (unless you're targeting exotic or legacy devices, which doesn't seem to be the case here).